# Wine and parallel processing

Tags: linux, wine, parallelism, lmde

I am running LMDE on my machine.

I was wondering if wine can support the parallel processing needs of some software.

Anyone knows any performance benchmarks for wine?

Comment: Any particular software in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Wine performs at native speed for some stuff, pretty bad for some other which have to be emulated. But performance isn't the biggest problem in wine: stuff not working is.

Most likely you would have better reliability using a windows virtual machine. However you should specify which software you plan to use, because whether wine is the right solution really depends on your application

Comment: I was thinking about some games.  I heard the new ones are using two or more cores and I would like to know if wine would support this feature to maximize performance.

Comment: as far as I know wine supports threading. For games, however, your main compatibility problems would be probably related to the graphic subset, particularly some different behavior between original directx and the emulated one. Look at www.winehq.org if your particular game is supposed to work or not.